# IHTMLElementCollection sometimes generates a UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: exception, mshtml

We use the IHTMLElementCollection in an ASP.NET 2.0 application.
Sometimes- not always - it gives us a UnauthorizedAccessException. I think it only happens on our server, and not locally.

I tried searching in searchdotnet.com, and found only 2 [results](http://www.searchdotnet.com/results.aspx?cx=002213837942349435108%3Ajki1okx03jq&q=IHTMLElementCollection+UnauthorizedAccessException&sa=Search+.NET+sites&cof=FORID%3A9#431), but in both of them the use of IHTMLElementCollection was the solution to that exception, not the cause...

What could make the IHTMLElementCollection generate that exception?

Comment: Do you mean mshtml::ihtmlelementcollection. In which case that is not ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes, I do mean that. Thank you for your correction. I will change the tag from ASP.NET 2.0 to mshtml